# Что хотел сделать человек?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Пытаюсь пофиксить ошибку в чужом коде:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Что-то не могу понять что хотел сделать человек в этом месте?  Добавить в датафрейм данные? (типа строку добавить?)

Вот код, чтобы реализовать данное место с данной ошибкой:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = [] #Приходит в это место пустой список
result = []  #Приходит в это место пустой список
result_frame = pd.DataFrame(result)
result_frame = result_frame[['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3'] + dates]
```

UPD:
Я правильно понимаю, что он хотел реализовать что-то типа такого?

```
result_frame.filter(['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3'] + dates)
```

Comment: Нет, тут из `result_frame` берутся колонки по суммарному списку `['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3'] + dates`. Видимо, раньше `result` не пустой приходил.

Comment: @CrazyElf, типа он хотел добавить новые колонки, которых нет в result_frame ?

Comment: Нет, он хотел взять из датафрейма часть колонок. `df[columns]` - так это делается. В вашем коде просто список колонок формируется из двух списков их сложением. `filter` я никогда не пользовался, но судя по описанию, наверное да, он делает тоже самое - выбирает часть колонок.

Comment: @CrazyElf, протестировал - filter так не работает. Получается, что ошибка в том, что из DataFrame код хочет взять поля, которых нет. В этом и ошибка получается.

Comment: ан нет ошибся - я просто забыл перезатереть отфильтрованный df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за пояснение @CrazyElf. Решение данной проблемы будет:

```
result_frame = result_frame.filter(items=['field_1', 'field_3'] + dates)
```

**filter** сам посмотрит каких нет полей и вернет только существующие

Comment: А, то есть filter не ругается, если полей каких-то нет из списка? Буду знать )